# How to iterate over 3 arrays of different sizes?

Tags: php

I have 3 arrays that **should** be of the same sizes, but sometimes they aren't. How can I pad them with the value "empty" while looping over them?

Say I have this:

```
array a -> { a , b , c};
array b -> { a , b , c, d};
array c -> { a , b , c, e, f};
```

the output should be:

```
array a -> { a , b , c, "empty", "empty", "empty"};
array b -> { a , b , c, d, "empty", "empty"};
array c -> { a , b , c, e, f};
```

i want to achieve the similar thing to these three arrays:

```
$flightplan_pdf_files = glob("{$scandir}/{$project}/flightplans/*.{pdf}", GLOB_BRACE);
$flightplan_zip_files = glob("{$scandir}/{$project}/flightplans/*.{zip}", GLOB_BRACE);
$flightplan_kml_files = glob("{$scandir}/{$project}/flightplans/*.{kml}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

here is my code:

```
$flightplan_pdf_files = glob("{$scandir}/{$project}/flightplans/*.{pdf}", GLOB_BRACE);
$flightplan_zip_files = glob("{$scandir}/{$project}/flightplans/*.{zip}", GLOB_BRACE);
$flightplan_kml_files = glob("{$scandir}/{$project}/flightplans/*.{kml}", GLOB_BRACE);


echo "<table class=\"table-list-search table table-striped table-hover\">";
//i assume the arrays are all the same length, so i just iterate over the first one,
//but if it sizes are not the same, how can i insert "empty" into them to make sure they are the same size?


for ($i = 0; $i < count($flightplan_zip_files); $i++)
{
    $zip = pathinfo($flightplan_zip_files[$i]);
    $zip = $zip['filename'] . ".zip";               
    $kml = pathinfo($flightplan_kml_files[$i]);
    $kml = $kml['filename'] . ".zip";   
    $pdf = pathinfo($flightplan_pdf_files[$i]);
    $pdf = $pdf['filename'] . ".zip";


    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><span class=\"pull-left\"><img src=\"http://110.142.4.9/atlass/scp/zip.gif\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"></span></td><td><span><a href=# onclick=\"test('" . $flightplan_zip_files[$i] . "');\">{$zip}</a></span></td>";   
    echo "<td><span class=\"pull-left\"><img src=\"http://110.142.4.9/atlass/scp/kml.jpg\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"></span></td><td><span><a href=# onclick=\"test('" . $flightplan_kml_files[$i] . "');\">{$kml}</a></span></td>";
    echo "<td><span class=\"pull-left\"><img src=\"http://110.142.4.9/atlass/scp/downloadpdf.jpg\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"></span></td><td><span><a href=# onclick=\"test('" . $flightplan_pdf_files[$i] . "');\">{$pdf}</a></span></td>";   
    echo "</tr>";
}


echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($flightplan_zip_files); $i++)
```

to this:

```
$length = max(count($flightplan_zip_files), count($flightplan_pdf_files), count($flightplan_kml_files));

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
```

and then put an if condition before each pathinfo to use the string `empty' when required.

There are other ways to do this, but this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the script I tested to achieve the result you are seeking. Give it a try it in your machine too..

Basically, First I am finding the largest array of three. Then I subtracted the smaller array from the largest array and then using `array_push`, I pushed empty into the array.

***I am providing this as an example to test and give you a hint. Please do not consider this as an ultimate solution :)***

```
<?php
$array1 = array('a','b','c');
$array2 = array('a','b','c','d');
$array3 = array('a','b','c','d','e');

$count_var1 = count($array1); 
$count_var2 = count($array2);
$count_var3 = count($array3);

if($count_var1 >= $count_var2 && $count_var1 >= $count_var3){
    $greatest = $count_var1;
}else if($count_var2 >= $count_var1 && $count_var2 >= $count_var3){
    $greatest = $count_var2;
}else if($count_var3 >= $count_var2 && $count_var3 >= $count_var3){
    $greatest = $count_var3;
}

$var_2_pad = $greatest-$count_var2;
$var_1_pad = $greatest-$count_var1;

for($i=1; $i<=$var_2_pad;$i++){
    $empty = 'empty';
    array_push($array2, $empty);
}

for($i=1; $i<=$var_1_pad;$i++){
    $empty = 'empty';
    array_push($array1, $empty);
}

echo "array2 = ";   print_r($array2);
echo "<br>";
echo "array3 = ";   print_r($array1);
echo "<br>";
echo "Original array = "; print_r($array3);

?>
```

Comment: instead of your if() conditions checking for the largest, you could use max()

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing anything in the $flightplan_... variables, just check to see if the array key exists?

```
if(array_key_exists($i, $flightplan_zip_files)) {
    ...
} else {
    $zip = "empty";
}
```

You too should update the loop condition as per **bluesmoon's answer** to make this work:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($flightplan_zip_files) || $i < count($flightplan_pdf_files) || $i < count($flightplan_kml_files); $i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggy backing off bluesmoon's answer.

What you need to do is find the length of the longest array, then iterate that many times.

```
// find longest array
$arrays = array($flightplan_pdf_files, $flightplan_zip_files, $flightplan_kml_files);
$longest_length = max($arrays) // edited as per bluesmoon's suggestion

// Now $longest_length will hold the length of the longest array

// now loop
for ($i = 0; $i < $longest_length; $i++){

}
```

Comment: you can use max() instead of iterating through the arrays.